# Unravel a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

Can anyone explain how I could simplify this LINQ query into multiple lines?

```
Data.StoredItems.GroupBy(i => i.Name, ((name, cps) => new { Name = name, Components = cps.Where(cp => cp.Name == name).GroupBy(cp => cp.Type, (type, components) => new { Type = type, List = components.ToList() }).ToList() }))
```

Comment: Well you can *start* by putting each parameter and method call onto a different line, which will massively increase the readability. I suggest you do that in the question.

Comment: You can always have funcs or expressions or actions declared and defined separately depending on the linq method you use and have them used in the linq expression

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to make it more readable, then you can do it like this:

```
Data.StoredItems
    .GroupBy(
        i => i.Name,
        ((name, cps) => new
        {
            Name = name,
            Components =
                cps //.Where(cp => cp.Name == name) This Where call here is redundant
                .GroupBy(
                    cp => cp.Type,
                    (type, components) => new
                    {
                        Type = type,
                        List = components.ToList()
                    })
                .ToList()
        }))
```

Please note that I removed the `Where` because it is not needed. Items in `cps` would already have `Name` equal to `name`.

Answer (score 0):

At each .[Method call] instead you can just store it in a collection and then just continue the chain on the next line.

For example:

var query = Data.StoredItems

var query2 = query.GroupBy(i => i.Name, ((name, cps) => new { Name = name,     Components = cps.Where(cp => cp.Name == name)

and continue on from there.

If it's just for debugging I might suggest you look into writing a "peek" code. like:

.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.toString);

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/linq-secrets-revealed-chaining-and-debugging/